# Code break when I'm trying to use an object methods in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, object, jquery-mobile

This is my class

```
var Player = function (name) {

        this.init(name);

    }

    $.extend(Player.prototype, {

        Name: '',
        Goals: 0,
        Fouls: 0,
        Holding: 0,
        Games: 0,
        Wins: 0,
       Taken: 0,


       init: function(name){

           this.Name = name;
           this.Goals= 0;
           this.Fouls= 0;
           this.Holding= 0;
           this.Games= 0;
           this.Wins= 0;
           this.Taken= 0;

       },
        setGoal: function (num) {
            this.Goals+= num;

        },
        setFouls: function (num) {
            this.Fouls+=num;
        },
        setHolding: function (holding) {
            this.Holding = (this.Holding * (this.Games-1) + holding) / (this.Games);
        },
        setGames: function () {

            this.Games+=1;
        },
        setWins: function () {

            this.Wins+=1;
        },
        setTaken: function (num) {

            this.Taken+=num;
        }
 });
```

I tryed many thing but evry time I'm trying to access a method after creating an instance of this class its just break and dont let me continues.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see you using the constructor being used.

It should be used this way:

```js
var Player = function(name) {
  this.init(name);

}

$.extend(Player.prototype, {

  Name: '',
  Goals: 0,
  Fouls: 0,
  Holding: 0,
  Games: 0,
  Wins: 0,
  Taken: 0,


  init: function(name) {

    this.Name = name;
    this.Goals = 0;
    this.Fouls = 0;
    this.Holding = 0;
    this.Games = 0;
    this.Wins = 0;
    this.Taken = 0;

  },
  setGoal: function(num) {
    this.Goals += num;

  },
  setFouls: function(num) {
    this.Fouls += num;
  },
  setHolding: function(holding) {
    this.Holding = (this.Holding * (this.Games - 1) + holding) / (this.Games);
  },
  setGames: function() {

    this.Games += 1;
  },
  setWins: function() {

    this.Wins += 1;
  },
  setTaken: function(num) {

    this.Taken += num;
  }
});
var p = new Player('Rayon');
p.setGoal(10);
alert(p.Name +' has scored '+p.Goals +' goals');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Obviously I use the constructor at first, it's ok with the object fileds but when I'm trying to use the object methods in a function the code break.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously I use the constructor at first, I forgot to mention that I'm using local storage, it's OK with the object fields but when I'm trying to use the methods the code break.